# Create a generic struct with Option<T> without specifying T when instantiating with None

Tags: rust

I have a

```
struct Foo<T>
where
    T: // ... some complex trait bound ...
{
    a: Bar,
    b: Option<T>,
}
```

When attempting to instantiate the struct with a `b: None` the compiler complains that it cannot infer the type and requires a type hint e.g. via the turbofish syntax. That is onerous on the caller because they will have to find a type that fulfills the trait bounds and import it despite not caring about that optional functionality.

I think what I am looking for would be a bottom type that automatically fulfills any trait bounds but cannot be instantiated so that `None::<Bottom>` could be used, but I have not found such a type in the documentation.

Comment: The bottom type is called `!` in Rust. Does it work for you?

Comment: Which part are you suggesting is onerous? If it's the turbofish aspect, how do you suggest the bottom type be specified other than that?

Comment: @MatthieuM. No, it does not match the trait bound.

Comment: @Shepmaster `::<!>` would be ok but it doesn't work anyway, `::<some potentially complex type that the user has to figure out first and needs to be imported>` is not. Note that those are trait bounds, so the API user would have to figure out a possible candidate type (that he doesn't even intend to instantiate!) just to pass `None`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [a feature in the works](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35121) that allows specifying the *never type* as `!`. This is not present in stable Rust, so you need to use a nightly and a feature flag:

```
#![feature(never_type)]

fn thing<T>() -> Option<T> {
    None
}

fn main() {
    thing::<!>();
}
```

However, this doesn't work for your case yet (this is part of the reason that it's unstable):

```
#![feature(never_type)]

trait NothingImplementsMe {}

fn thing<T>() -> Option<T> 
    where T: NothingImplementsMe,
{
    None
}

fn main() {
    thing::<!>();
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `!: NothingImplementsMe` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     thing::<!>();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `NothingImplementsMe` is not implemented for `!`
   |
   = note: required by `thing`
```

The very first unresolved question on the tracking issue is:

> What traits should we implement for `!`?

---

Since this feature is both unstable and doesn't do what you want, you may want to consider creating your own bespoke "bottom" type:

```
trait AlmostNothingImplementsMe {
    fn foo();
}

struct Nope;
impl AlmostNothingImplementsMe for Nope {
    fn foo() { unimplemented!() }
}

fn thing<T>() -> Option<T> 
    where T: AlmostNothingImplementsMe,
{
    None
}

fn main() {
    thing::<Nope>();
}
```

To improve the UX of this, I'd suggest creating a builder of some type that starts you off with the faux-bottom type:

```
mod nested {
    pub trait AlmostNothingImplementsMe {
        fn foo();
    }

    pub struct Nope;
    impl AlmostNothingImplementsMe for Nope {
        fn foo() { unimplemented!() }
    }

    pub fn with_value<T>(t: T) -> Option<T> 
        where T: AlmostNothingImplementsMe,
    {
        Some(t)
    }

    pub fn without_value() -> Option<Nope> {
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    nested::without_value();
}
```

You can see this similar pattern [in crates like Hyper](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.10.4/hyper/client/struct.Client.html), although it boxes the concrete type so you don't see it from the outside.

Comment: @trentcl: It's a work in progress, there are many things that don't work with uninhabited types that one would expect to work.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment and making you look like talking to yourself! For others, what I asked (before Shepmaster edited his answer to include the information) was "But does `!` implement any trait bound?"

Answer (score 2):

One option to avoid the need to the turbofish operator is to have a type alias:

```
trait MyTrait {}
impl MyTrait for () {}

struct Foo<T: MyTrait> {
    i: isize,
    o: Option<T>,
}

type Bar = Foo<()>;

fn main() {
    let foo_default = Bar { i: 1, o: None };
}
```

I used `()` as the default for simplicity, but `!` (when available) or your own bottom type as in @Shepmaster's answer may be better.

A constructor function could also work if you don't mind `Foo::new_default(i)` or similar.

Comment: `()` does not fulfill trait bounds and they cannot be implemented when the traits come from external crates

Comment: You haven't said what the bounds are; I am suggesting implementing them (in some reasonable default way, possibly involving `unreachable!()` or `assert!()`) for some kind of default type (`()` as an example) and using that as the default.

Comment: But it is not a general solution since it assumes that all traits are crate-local.

Comment: True it's not general; I was just offering an option which might work in some similar cases. As I mentioned a custom type could be substituted instead of `()` which would resolve the non-local trait issue.